# angular test case $scope.$apply

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Why is it mandatory to execute `$scope.$apply()` in a test case for async process to finish.

say i have a service

```
angular.service("a",function($q){
    return {
        getValue: function(){
            return $q.resolve(someObj)
        }
    }
})
```

And in my test

```
it("test this",function(done){
    a.getValue()
    .then(function(data){
        expect(data).toEqual(data)
        done();
    })
    $scope.$apply();
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It triggers the digest cycle.

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing):

> When testing promises, it's important to know that the resolution of
>   promises is tied to the digest cycle. That means a promise's then,
>   catch and finally callback functions are only called after a digest
>   has run. In tests, you can trigger a digest by calling a scope's
>   $apply function. If you don't have a scope in your test, you can
>   inject the $rootScope and call $apply on it.

For http calls, you use $httpBackend.flush(). From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend),

> The $httpBackend used in production always responds to requests
>   asynchronously. If we preserved this behavior in unit testing, we'd
>   have to create async unit tests, which are hard to write, to follow
>   and to maintain. But neither can the testing mock respond
>   synchronously; that would change the execution of the code under test.
>   For this reason, the mock $httpBackend has a flush() method, which
>   allows the test to explicitly flush pending requests. This preserves
>   the async api of the backend, while allowing the test to execute
>   synchronously.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @scott
Can you elaborate why does a promise require a digest cycle to run when i'm not changing anything on the scope.

Comment: From this [post](http://blog.xebia.com/testing-promises-in-angularjs/): When a promise is resolved, its callbacks are not called immediately. Instead, Angular puts the promise.resolve callbacks on the evalAsync queue. There they wait until the queue will be processed. Only then the callbacks will be called. It is the digest() method that processes the queue.